# Mysql Search Treat Periods Like Spaces

Tags: php, mysql

well right now I have a bunch of data stored in my db in the format.

`this.is.the.name`

where instead of having a space, there is a period.

I'm just wondering how I could do my mysql search to treat the periods like spaces? Or just have it so if a user searches "this is the" it'll return the entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing the replace on the field, like other answers suggest, you could do the **replace on the search term**. In this way MySQL could still use an index on `field1`. Supposing that the periods are always there instead of spaces

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE field1 = REPLACE('user input', ' ', '.')
```

If you want to visualise without dots you could do the reverse replace in the `SELECT` part too:

```
SELECT REPLACE(field1, '.', ' '), field2 FROM table 
WHERE field1 = REPLACE('user input', ' ', '.')
```

Or you can even consider to update your DB, instead of fighting with it:

```
UPDATE table SET field1 = REPLACE(field1, '.', ' ')
```

Comment: Since replace is used once per query rather than once per row, this should be more efficient. It is the best answer as long as the periods ALWAYS replace spaces in that field.

Comment: Yeah that's the issue, all though there are very few instances where there are actually spaces instead of periods, their still there. Although I may use this approach! :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `replace` function of mysql in your `WHERE` clausole:

```
replace([field_name],'[string_to_find]','[string_to_replace]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function.

```
 SELECT REPLACE('this.is.the.name', '.', ' ');

 --> 'this is the name'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a [regular expression search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) to find entries that match.  You will have to do a little pre-processing before you search the database.

Use the underscore character as a single wildcard:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE "this_is_the_%";
# returns
#  - this.is.the.name
#  - this-is-the-name
#  - this.is_the_name
#  - this is the name
```

Check out the REGEXP search too.