# Mysql: How to strip out all the but letters and numbers in a column before performing a LIKE with a given string

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I wish to know how google does their search, say there is a road called St. John's Road in my database and I type in my ajax-auto-sugestion field...

St John

How can I get the auto-selection to show the road that is LIKE the content but do not use the . or the ' in the database

If I was to start to type...

St. John

then it would of course show the suggestion as I used the .

Can this be done ?

My fields have the proper names of the roads and I use utf8_general_ci for the road name field and the LIKE method to get the results.

Comment: If you want to do this on-the-fly, it’ll cause quite bad performance. Better to have an additional column that has the value in the format `stjohnsroad` or something like that in the first place, and have an index on that and use that for searching (after applying the same treatment to the search keyword as well).

Comment: while retrieving the data from database you can remove those character using your backend lang like php

Answer (score 0):

What are you using on the server for users to interface with your MySQL server?  Typically people use something like PHP to process information between the database and the HTML on the user's side.

To do this purely in MySQL (which I'm not sure is what you're trying to accomplish), you can use 
`UPDATE table
   SET field_name = replace( replace(field_name, '.', ''), '"'. ' ' );`

This will replace period with no white space as the same, and periods with whitespace with just a space.

It's easier in my opinion to do this sort of stuff in PHP, you can use [str_replace](http://www.php.net/str_replace).

This way you'll end up using

`$address = ($_POST['address']);
$address = str_replace('.', '', $address);`

This can be done before writing your `LIKE` statement in MySQL.  You can read some more about the `LIKE` statement here: [MySQL Like Operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Where `$_POST['address']` is returned from the `<input>` element the user typed the address in, and submitted through form.  Doing this for and autocomplete / autoselect in ajax is a bit more difficult, as it's not trivial to send AJAX requests like that on typing actions.  Surely someone else can help explain that, but the only time I have ever done an AJAX based autosuggest, I've preloaded the array from MySQL through PHP.  I'm sure google doesn't do that.

Comment: Yes I am using ajax to retrieve the results, So using a strip all but letters, numbers and spaces seems the better option for me at the moment.  As for having a separate column with only letters, numbers and the spaces.  This seems counter productive, or have I missed the point.  I currently have just under 50000 entries and it is growing.  I understand the method or using a different column for the search but this would cause the table to be just a bit under twice the size it is at the moment.

Comment: But when the user is entering the search information you can ignore the `.` and / or strip it out when querying the server.  You shouldn't have to modify your database.

Comment: so if i take out all but letters and numbers from the text entered and query the database with that phrase it will still return say...

St. John's Road (which is what text is in my table)

even if they entered...

st johns

I am unable to try this at the moment as my host is migrating to another server.

Comment: Ok just tried that suggestion but it did not return the results as expected.

The database has the exact phrase...

St. John's Road

including the single quote and the dot.  What I am after is a way to allow the visitor to type in the ajax form field something like...

st john

no quotes or dot, and for the St. John's Road to show up as shown in my database.

Comment: There is a suggestion to have a copy of the column of roads and remove all special characters and do a search on that, ok I could also have the search done on the original column as well just in case they do type in the St. John's  (dot and quote) version.  But still my issue is that I would have to double the size of the table, as at present it is pretty large and this would just cause more burden on the server.

Comment: See this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7778507/2002412

You can alter the search from the user to include periods, although this is a pretty tricky way if users may be entering the period, or may not.  

I still think a combination of the `LIKE` term and `%` wildcard will give you results you need.  You're not the first person to need to search this way, and plenty of databases have things stored this way.